# WPF ListBoxItem Visibility and ScrollBar

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, visibility, listboxitem

I was hoping to collapse certain ListBoxItems based on a property of their data context.

I came up with the following (trimmed for brevity)

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceColumns}">
     <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDeleted}" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
              </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding ColumnName}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This "works" in that it does collapse the listboxitems that are marked as "IsDeleted", however the vertical scrollbar does not adjust for the "missing" items.  As I'm scrolling, all of a sudden the bar gets bigger and bigger (without moving) until I scroll past the point of the hidden items, and then finally starts to move.

I also tried explicitly setting the height and width to 0 as well in the data trigger, to no avail.

Does anyone know if there's a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Enter CollectinViewSource

One thing you can do is connect your ListBox to your items through a CollectionViewSource.

What you do is create the collectionViewSource in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsItems"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Connect to it in your CodeBehind or ViewModel

```
Dim cvsItems as CollectionViewSource
cvsItems = MyWindow.FindResource("cvsItems")
```

and set it's source property to your collection of items.

```
cvsItems.Source = MyItemCollection
```

Then you can do filtering on it.  The collectionViewSource maintains all of the items in the collection, but alters the View of those items based on what you tell it.

## Filtering

To filter, create a CollectionView using your CollectionViewSource:

```
Dim MyCollectionView as CollectionView = cvsItems.View
```

Next write a filtering function:

```
Private Function FilterDeleted(ByVal item As Object) As Boolean
    Dim MyObj = CType(item, MyObjectType)
    If MyObj.Deleted = True Then Return False Else Return True End If
End Function
```

Finally, write something that makes the magic happen:

```
MyCollectionView .Filter = New Predicate(Of Object)(AddressOf FilterDeleted)
```

I usually have checkboxes or Radiobuttons in a hideable expander that lets me change my filtering options back and forth.  Those are bound to properties each of which runs the filter function which evaluates all the filters and then returns whether the item should appear or not.

Let me know if this works for you.

## Edit:

I almost forgot:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsItems}}"/>
```

Comment: Ahh the good ol' collectionviewsource. My solution will require it to be a bit more dynamic, but I'll give it a shot. Thank you.

Comment: I have done some pretty neat things with the CollectionViewSource.  I have made a continuous filter (Filter as you type), and written filter and group methods that can affect objtects 20 different ways.  What I really want though is a way to animate against the CollectionViewSource.  The problem that I have with it is it refreshes the view whenever you apply a filter or what have you.  When it does that, it reloads all of the items.  But what if I wanted the filtered out items to fade and then collapse?  Can't seem to do that...

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks.  I usually just bind to observable collections for simplicity's sake, but then I tend to forget about the CollectionViewSource option in a more complex scenario.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to set the VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtual="False" in your listbox.

[Why don't my listboxitems collapse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128908/why-dont-my-listboxitems-collapse)